# Set product reviews limit and pagination

Tags: product, review, pager, collection

I have large number of product reviews being displayed on product detail page.

I need to count the total number of reviews and set limit on the number of reviews displayed and with pagination.

Does Magento default has this feature ?

How can I achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select one of the answers as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's simple to add these lines to local.xml file

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" />
    <block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" />
     <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product_customer_reviews" as="product_customer_reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
        <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block> 
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this [link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-collection-paging) which is explaining on [Add Paging to a Custom Collection](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-collection-paging). I'd used this for my custom module and the paging was working exactly as expected.

In your case you must set your collection of review to paging. You may need to customize the template files as well. Hope you knows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I do not want to make a custom module for pagination. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: are you using magento's review or is there your own?

Comment: No Magento's default review

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default theme has a pager for the `<review_product_list>` handle.

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar" />
```

Make sure if you are using a custom theme that this is included, you can double check with `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/review.xml` to see how the default theme works with the pager.

It should get added to the `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` when there is a child block with the correct name.

```
if ($toolbar = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_review_list.toolbar')) {
    $toolbar->setCollection($this->getReviewsCollection());
    $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
}
```